# Array join break tag displayed as text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code

```
 return $('.status-message.form-error').text($.map(messages, function(m) {
    return m.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + m.slice(1);
  }).join("<br />"));
```

and for some reason it returns the `<br />` as text, so the result on the webpage is:

```
Your security code is incorrect.<br />Lorem ipsum<br />
```

I'm not able to realize what I'm doing wrong here, I've checked for similar questions but the answer seem to have the exact same code that I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) which converts anything you pass to it into raw text.

Instead, you should be using [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which, you guessed it, changes the actual HTML.

```
//                                     ****
return $('.status-message.form-error').html($.map(messages, function(m) {
  return m.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + m.slice(1);
}).join("<br />"));
```